# Error testing connection to multiple LDAP servers

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, wildfly

I'm developing a java web application that needs to connect to an Active Directory server (LDAP) in order to authenticate some users. It's working fine, but I'm trying to configure it to be able to connect to 2 different servers. So I put this syntax in my Properties:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, 
        "LDAP://" + ParametrosManager.readParametro("LDAP_PROVIDER_URL") + ":636 " +
        "LDAP://" + ParametrosManager.readParametro("LDAP_PROVIDER_URL2") + ":636" 
        );
System.out.println(env.get(Context.PROVIDER_URL));
// it prints LDAP://psfjfhsj.com.br:636 LDAP://myRealLdap.com.br:636
```

So there they are, two space separated ldap URLs. The first isn't a real address, the second one is one of my ldap servers. But my connection attempts are failing because my application can't find the first server! Here's some console output:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: psfjfhsj.com.br:636 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: psfjfhsj.com.br]
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226)
 (...)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: psfjfhsj.com.br
```

I'm debugging ssl connections (using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` flag in my server) and I can see that my true host (`myRealLdap.com.br`) connects and handshakes OK. Of course the fake URL can't be found, but isn't this a realistic simulation for a "server down" ?

I'm using a `wildfly 9.0.2` server with `openjdk 1.8.0_242`.

Thanks

Comment: It would be more likely you would get destination host unreachable or connect refused. Are you sure that's the right way to list multiple servers?

Comment: I find it funny too, but it seems to be the right approach. Here are some links indicating it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459280/i-need-to-use-multiple-ldap-provider-how-can-i-check-ldap-server-availability and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html

Comment: Did you try to use the following commands?

// Create initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
// See which server was used
System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment().get(Context.PROVIDER_URL));?

Comment: If I use `realHost1.com realHost2.com`, the print only shows the address of the first one.
If I use `fakeHost.com realHost2.com`, it prints only the URL of the real host, despite it being the second URL in the list, and gives me the CommunicationException.

Comment: I guess that's an openjdk issue (maybe not implemented?). I cannot find any reference to this multi-url option in the openjdk documentation. Can you change JDK an try with oracle since according to the link posted by @BrunoLamps there is support on that?

Comment: Hi @rakwaht ! Just tested it in a windows 10 environment with oracle jdk 8, same error message unfortunatelly. =(

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html) the code you implemented should support this:

> Instead of just one URL, you can also supply a space-separated list of
>   URLs. In this case, the LDAP provider will attempt to use each URL in
>   turn until it is able to create a successful connection. The LDAP
>   provider will then set the Context.PROVIDER_URL property to the
>   successful URL, so that the application can determine which URL is
>   being used.

According to your stack trace we have `UnknownHostException` and in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) it states that it is thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined. Basically this error is thrown for a DNS miss.

Looking deeper on the internet I found others with an issue quite close to yours (same error during LDAP connection ([here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/jira-server-fails-to-connect-to-ldap-server-with-unknownhostexception-299571071.html), [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuration-task-cannot-communicate-ldap-server) and [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/ldap-sync-throws-communicationexception-unknownhostexception-969538564.html)).
All those issue were solved by updating the DNS to include the hostname which was unknown.

**This leads to my interpretation of the Oracle documentation.**
When they say, the *LDAP provider will attempt to use each URL in turn until it is able to create a successful connection* they mean that the connection could be refused because the server is down, not because it does not exist.

Comment: Last minute idea: you can check out if IPs are supported instead of hostnames, with that you would skip the DNS problem I guess

Comment: I'll test it with existent but offline network hosts, thanks @rakwaht!

Comment: Hi, I just tried a host that exists, is registered in our dns, but is down. And I got a 'javax.naming.CommunicationException: xxxxxxx.xxx.xx.gov.br:636 [Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)]`. Unfortunatelly it didn't work.

Comment: But the error changed, therefore I guess you can keep digging